# load a code sections depends on screen resolution

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have desktop version of my site and I want to make a responsive site for mobile devices, but the content of one of my pages which I include from php file is whole different for mobile version. I could put the desktop content and mobile content into DIVs in one file and use `display:none display:block` but it seems to be not ergonomic way for larger contents. What are the standards today for solving such a problem? I've search on the internet and there are some solutions with display or js load file as answers for people's questions, but I'm asking more for the standards, an ergonomic way of solving this. If I'm wrong then just correct me, but maybe the best way is just to put everything in one file and operate with css (display code).

Comment: How is the content different? Does mobile version have less content or is it just different?

Comment: The content is different, different element setup, my use additional scripts like jquery accordion and so on.

Comment: If you have fundamentally different pages, you could maybe try one of the options here: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/mobile-redirect

Comment: There are more like a different blocks of content (where arrangement of elements are different from desktop version) than a whole page. Like header of footer are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I use in my Websites some kind of "adaptive" Webdesign.
A PHP Script checks wether is a Mobile device or a desktop device.
In each desktop and mobile site is some CSS with the
@media (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 1200px){
}
You can choose some different min and max values. With this layout it is easy for me to design for different display sizes.
Hope this solved your problem

Comment: This can be a solution where I can include a php content that I need at the time. I don't have experience how reliable is this method of using php scripts (with user-agent analysis) for checking if it's mobile device or not. I found [mobiledetect.net](http://mobiledetect.net/). The script must be enough reliable to give up using iex. only css like display: none.

Comment: @soonic [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries) the Media Queries are supported by the most browsers. For not supported browsers you can add a extra css. Do you have any specific question about your problem or is it solved?